# Html5 Coloured dropdown's not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried everything, every way of giving a dropdown field a given colour, using a seperat css link, css style inside the option etc. Stripped it down so they are no frameworks, and still nothing. I'm using Bootstrap right now, and this is my current code for giving a dropdown option a colour, if anyone could help that would be great.
As you can see the first option is with the given colour as a test, although no success :/

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="type" name="type" class=" control-label" for="textinput">Online Friend List Color</label>
  <div class="">
    <select id="type" name="type">

      <option class="red" style="background-color:#fff;color:#fff;" id="" name="" value="255, 0, 0">Red</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="255, 128, 0">Orange</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="255, 255, 0">Yellow</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="128, 255, 0">Lime</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="0, 255, 0">Green</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="0, 255, 255">Tequil</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="0, 128, 255">Light Blue</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="0, 0, 255">Dark Blue</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="127, 0, 255">Purple</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="255, 0, 255">Pink</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="0, 0, 0">Black</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="128, 128, 128">Grey</option>
      <option id="type" name="type" value="255, 255, 255">White</option>


    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate Id's aren't valid in html. They must be **unique**

Comment: Why are you using type as id so often?

Comment: It was a copy and paste, just changed the id & name to the correct colour, still no luck. Might try it on my pc just to check if its to do with MacOS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either:

- different classes for different css, or
- different id's, and select by them.

DEMO:

```css
#type0 {
  background: red;
}
#type1 {
  background: orange;
}
#type2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#type3 {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="labelType" name="type" class=" control-label" for="textinput">Online Friend List Color</label>
  <div class="">
    <select id="type" name="type">
      <option id="type0" name="" value="255, 0, 0">Red</option>
      <option id="type1" name="type" value="255, 128, 0">Orange</option>
      <option id="type2" name="type" value="255, 255, 0">Yellow</option>
      <option id="type3" name="type" value="128, 255, 0">Lime</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this works only in Chrome and to some extent in Firefox you can achieve what you want. Otherwise, unfortunately, there is no cross browser pure CSS solution for styling a select element. An alternative, however, would be to 'create' your own select element:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid purple;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width:150px;
}
li {
  margin:0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
div > ul {
  display: none;
}
div:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  margin-left:-40px;
}

#one{background:red;}
#two{background:yellow;}
#three{background:blue;}
```

```html
<div>
  Select
  <ul>
    <li id="one">Red
    </li>
    <li id="two">Yellow
    </li>
    <li id="three">Blue
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

## Alternative

---

In order to 'keep' the option tags, you may be interested in something like a jquery plugin for something like this:

- [example](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/select-list)

Comment: Just tried that, no luck. And did it on a blank Html page

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: That's great, is there anyway I can inplement it to use `option` rather than `li`

Comment: unfortunately, I believe **<option>** is only valid within the **<select>** tag, so i *believe* not, (although could possibly be wrong). But as it stands, I think it would be safer to not use the option tag for this functionality.

Comment: Hmm, I do need the option though, as the values for the given options will be submitted into the database later.

Comment: you can use jquery/script for this

Comment: Do you have any examples or sites I could follow to use this for the option tag?

Comment: @SARUAV: [here](http://codepen.io/silverdrop/pen/msrcE), [here](http://codepen.io/scverano/pen/zsqLx) or [here](http://codepen.io/patrneal/pen/fhxgB) or even [here](http://codepen.io/Goldbio/pen/qfJpu)

Comment: Damn the first one is perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: All working although the colour picker isn't being shown. I've included the CSS,HTML,JS
But the Js doesn't seem to be shown for some reason

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="type" name="type" class=" control-label" for="textinput">Online Friend List Color</label>
  <div class="">
    <select id="type" name="type">
      <option style="background-color: #F00; color: #FFF;">Red</option>
      <option style="background-color: #0F0; color: #FFF">Green</option>
      <option style="background-color: #000; color: #FFF;">Black</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Works fine for me.

BUT: If you want to change the color of the select itself, i recommend using javascript to detect changes within the `<select>` tag and change the color then:

```html
<select style="background-color: #F00; color: #FFF;">
  <option style="background-color: #F00; color: #FFF;">Red</option>
  <option style="background-color: #0F0; color: #FFF">Green</option>
  <option style="background-color: #000; color: #FFF;">Black</option>
</select>
<!-- Some javascript stuff... -->
```

EDIT:

```html
<body>
    <script>
        function updateSelect(color) {
         document.getElementById('select_color').style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    </script>
    <select id="select_color" style="background-color: #F00; color: #888;" onchange="updateSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id);">
      <option id="red" style="background-color: #F00; color: #888;">Red</option>
      <option id="lime" style="background-color: #0F0; color: #888">Green</option>
      <option id="black" style="background-color: #000; color: #888;">Black</option>
      <option id="white" style="background-color: #FFF; color: #888;">White</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Now it should work just fine :)

Comment: The second snippet worked. Could it be that it just doesn't like to work on a mac? It sounds stupid but just a thought

Comment: Do you mean the background of the select itself or the background of all options? What browser are you using?

Comment: Either, just so the user can visually see which colour it is. But the background of all the options would be preferred. I'm using Chrome, and I tried Safari too.

Comment: It works on both browsers (but I'm on windows...), so if you want me to do the javascript stuff, i would do a little research on updating the background color of the select element. But I don't understand: do you see any color?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind doing the Javascript parts that would be great. Well on the last snippet you put I can see the default option is red, but when I select any others it stays red even on black. :/

Comment: Yeah of course :D As I mentioned in the HTML comment or above the snippet, that has to be done with js. I will do this in about 5 mins or so :D